# Ubuntu 14.04 IPv6 auto method with dhcp option

Tags: 14.04

I am attempting to provision an IPv6 interface under /etc/network/interfaces with the following configuration

```
# /etc/network interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 auto
dhcp 1
```

The interface is configured appropriately with the two expected automatic assignments ( privext and EUI-64) as well as a default route through the RA.  What I don't see any values provided by the stateless DHCPv6 server.

I ran a packet capture and am able to see a DHCPv6 Information-Request and  corresponding reply with the expected "DNS recursive name server" value I am expecting.  I do not see this value reflected in /etc/resolv.conf.

if I change the configuration to the following:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
accept_ra 1
```

This configuration produces the expected output of all stateless addresses (EUI-64 and privext), DHCPv6 stateful assignment,and the options from DHCPv6 (including "DNS recursive name server" assignment in /etc/resolv.conf").

My RAs currently have the O flag set.  I have tried various combinations of the M and O bits to no avail.  Is stateless DHCPv6 in the auto Method broken or am I just missing something?